# Why checking a non-existing hash key only take O(1) complexity?

Tags: data-structures, time-complexity

If a key doesn't exist in the hash table, how do you actually check its non-existence in a hash table? Do you need to compare the key value to every other existing keys?
Thank you.

Comment: In a hash table, keys are used as indices. For instance if the array used for the hash table has size 512, then a key is a number between 0 and 255. Accessing a cell of an array given its index is O(1). When you access the cell, the cell is either marked as "empty" or gives a list of the elements stored there. If the cell is empty, then the key is "non-existent".

Comment: Thank you @Stef! This answered my question.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have created a hash Table of 5 numbers(1-5);
Create a hashmap of 5 numbers with initialize every value of hashmap as 0;

```
 map<int,int>hashmap;
      hashmap[1] = 0 
      hashmap[2]=  0
      hashmap[3] = 0
      hashmap[4] = 0
      hashmap[5] = 0
    
    int arr[6] = {1,2,3,3,4,4};
```

Now, find the occurence of every value of array in hashmap by iterating it over the array.

```
for(int i =0; i< arr.size(); i++)
      {
       hashmap[arr[i]]++;
      }
```

Now, see the Hashmap  again :

```
          hashmap[1]  = 1
          hashmap[2]  = 1
          hashmap[3] =  2
          hashmap[4] =  2
          hashmap[5] =  0
```

Suppose you have to check the occurence of element 5 in the hash map.
Then simply check in the hashmap.

```
                if(hashmap[5] == 0)
                    cout<<"Dosen't Exist"<<endl
                else
                    cout<<"Exist"<<endl;
```

After preprocessing the hash map we can check whether the key exists or not in 0(1) .

Answer (score 1):

The hash of the non-existing key will correspond to some bucket. You will need to check every element in that bucket to see if it is the element you are looking for, which of course none of them will be. So the amount of work you have to do is equal to the number of objects in the bucket.

In a typical hash map, the number of buckets is O(N), so the number of objects in the average bucket is O(1). Thus the cost to search for a non-existing object will also be O(1).

Answer (score 0):

In a hash table, keys are used as indices. For instance if the array used for the hash table has size 512, then a key is a number between 0 and 255. Accessing a cell of an array given its index is O(1). When you access the cell, the cell is either marked as "empty" or gives a list of the elements stored there. If the cell is empty, then the key is "non-existent".